# Добавить цвет тексту в XSSFWorkbook()

Tags: java

```
Делаю оформление для exel отчета. нужно чтобы ячейка была черной а текст внутри ее белый.
```

как сделать текст белым?

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFColor baseBackgroungColor6 = new XSSFColor(Color.decode("#000000"));
    XSSFCellStyle titleStyleBLACK = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    tittleFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    titleStyleBLACK.setFont(tittleFont);
    titleStyleBLACK.setFillForegroundColor(baseBackgroungColor6);
    titleStyleBLACK.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    titleStyleBLACK.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так

```
font = wb.createFont();
font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
titleStyleBLACK.setFont(font);
```